# Reference script container element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a handle on the DOM element that contains the script inside it. So if I had:

```
<script type="text/javascript> var x = ?; </script>
```

Is there a way that I can assign "x" a reference to the script element that contains "x"?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? For instance, if you're thinking you could remove the `script` element to remove that script from the document, that doesn't work. The JavaScript from the `script` tag, once executed, is loaded into the JavaScript runtime memory area and is unaffected by changes to the `script` tag (including complete removal of it). I'm sure there are other uses for getting the `script` tag that **do** work, just asking the question... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include some marker text in the script element, and then (similar to what David said), you can loop through all the `script` elements in the DOM (using `getElementsByTagName` or whatever features your library, if you're using one, may have). That should find the element reliably. That would look something like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/udawe4)):

```
<body>
  <script id='first' type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
      var x = "MARKER:first";
    })();
  </script>
  <script id='second' type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
      var x = "MARKER:second";
    })();
  </script>
  <script id='third' type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
      var x = "MARKER:third";
    })();
  </script>
  <script id='last' type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
      var scripts, index, script;

      scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
      for (index = 0; index < scripts.length; ++index) {
        script = scripts[index];
        if (script.innerHTML.indexOf("MARKER:second") >= 0
           && script.id !== "last") {
          display("Found MARKER:second in script tag #" + script.id);
        }
      }

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

Note that, like the script above, if you're looking for a script tag marker from within a *different* script tag, you'll need to handle that. Above it's handled by checking the ID of the script tag, but you can also just break it up in the one you don't want to find, like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/udawe4/2)):

```
if (script.innerHTML.indexOf("MARKER:" + "second") >= 0) {
  display("Found MARKER:" + "second in script tag #" + script.id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a truly safe way.

The closest you can come is to use `getElementsByTagName` to get all the scripts, get its length, get the last script element, then work from there.

This can fail if the script is deferred or if the script has been dynamically added to the page before another script element.